# Undefined Method With DL::Importer

Tags: ruby, rubydl

The debugger states that the method message is undefined is it becuase it is nested in C and if so how do i change this

```
class LiveMIDI
  module C
    extend DL::Importer
    dlload '/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMIDI.framework/Versions/Current/CoreMIDI'

    extern "int MIDIClientCreate(void *, void *, void *,void *)"
    extern "int MIDIClientDispose(void *)"
    extern "int MIDIGetNumberOfDestinations()"
    extern "void * MIDIGetDestination(int)"
    extern "int MIDIOutputPortCreate(void *, void *, void *)"
    extern "void * MIDIPacketListInit(void *)"
    extern "void * MIDIPacketListAdd(void *, int, void *, int, int, int, void *)"
    extern "int MIDISend(void *, void *,void *)"

    module CF
      extend DL::Importer
      dlload '/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/Current/CoreFoundation'

      def _message(*args)
        format = "C" * args.size
        bytes = args.pack(format).to_ptr
        packet_list = DL.malloc(256)
        packet_ptr = C.mIDIPacketListInit(packet_list)
        packet_ptr = C.mIDIPacketListAdd(packet_list, 256, packet_ptr, 0, 0, args.size, bytes)
        C.mIDISend(@outport, @destination, packet_list)

        extern "void * CFStringCreateWithCString (void *, char *, int)"

        def open
          client_name = CF.cFStringCreateWithString(nil, "RubyMIDI", 0)
          @client = DL::PtrData.new(nil)
          C.mIDIClientCreate(client_name, nil, nil, @client.ref)

          port_name = CF.cFStringCreateWithString(nil, "Output", 0)
          @output = DL::PttD6ata.new(nil)
          C.mIDIOutputPortCreate(@client, port_name, @outport.ref)

          num = C.mIDIGetNumberOfDestinations()
          raise NoMIDIDestinations if num < 1
          @destination = C.mIDIGetDestination(0)
        end
        def close
          C.mIDIClientDispose(@client)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```